# How to better understand for "longest valid parentheses" problem solution?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

The problem is:

> Given a string containing just the characters '(' and ')', find the length of the longest valid (well-formed) parentheses substring

Some examples are:

> Input: "(()", output: 2
>
> Input: ")()())", output 4

I found this working Python solution below:

```
def solution(s):
    if not s or len(s) == 1:
        return 0

    stack = [-1]
    a = 0
    for i,c in enumerate(s):
        if c == '(':
            stack.append(i)
        else:
            stack.pop()
            if stack:
                a = max(a, i - stack[-1])
            else:
                stack.append(i) 
    return a
```

I'm having trouble understanding why this solution works. I've worked step-by-step on some example inputs, but I can't see why it works.

If I understand correctly, the stack is simply appending the indices every time a left parentheses is encountered. Otherwise, the stack is popped and we're taking the difference between the current index and the last left parentheses.

My question is why is the stack popped first and then the length is measured? Why are we measuring from the 2nd to last parentheses? I'm also failing to understand why we have a `stack.append(i)` if the stack is empty: I don't understand the logic here.

Comment: Try working a few examples by hand, using the steps shown in the code. That's right, by hand: with pencil and paper. "push" things onto the stack and "pop" them off. Write down what happens. That should give you an idea of what's going on.

Comment: This problem doesn't require a stack or anything remotely complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack contains indexes of unbalanced characters, always in increasing order. The top of the stack (i.e. the last value in the `stack` list) is the rightmost character that is currently unbalanced (or a special index of `-1` that refers to a position "before the beginning" of the string if there are not any unbalanced characters currently).

At the bottom of the stack is the index of the rightmost unbalanced `)` character, or `-1` if there has been no unbalanced `)`s seen so far. All of the other values in the stack will always be indexes of so-far unbalanced `(` characters. We might balance them later, as we continue to iterate over the string.

When we come to a new character in our iteration over the input string, there are three possible actions we might take.

1. If the new character is a `(`, we know it is unbalanced (for now, since it's the last character we've processed), so we always push it onto top of the stack.

In the other two cases, the new character is `)`. For both, we want to pop a value off the top of the stack, since the former value is no longer the rightmost unbalanced character.

2. If the stack is not empty after we pop a value, then the popped index represented an unbalanced `(` character, and the current `)` has just balanced it.

   In this case, our current character is part of a balanced substring, so we check if it's the longest such substring we've seen so far. The last value in the stack is the index of the rightmost unbalanced character, and our balanced substring begins just to its right. The length of the current substring is thus `i - stack[-1]`, and the `max` call will replace `a` (the length of the longest substring seen previously) with this new length if it's larger than `a`'s old value.
3. If the stack is empty after we popped a value, then the value we popped was the bottom of the stack. As I mentioned above, the bottom value is an index of an unbalanced `)` character (or `-1` representing the start of the string). If we've popped it, that means our current `)` is unbalanced! In this case, we replace the popped value with our own index. This is the new bottom of the stack, the index of the a new rightmost unbalanced `)`.